# Jordan Form of a 3x3 Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, jordan-normal-form

I'm having some  troubles figuring out  Jordan Canonical Form. Can someone explain how to get there with this example matrix?

$A=\begin{bmatrix}-1&0&3\\-3&2&2\\0&0&2\end{bmatrix}$

Also how i can get the tranformations matrix to write 
$A$=$PJP^{(-1)}$

Comment: Have you tried finding the eigenvalues at least?

Comment: Yep , they are -1 , and  2 ( of mutiplicity 2)

Answer (score 1):

Since the matrix have $\lambda_1=-1$ and $\lambda_{2,3}=2$ the [Jordan form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) is given by

$$J=\begin{bmatrix}2&1&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}$$

and to find the Jordan basis we can use that

$$A=PJP^{-1} \implies AP=PJ$$

and by $P=[u,v,w]$ we obtain

$$Au=2u$$ $$Av=u+2v$$  $$Aw=-w$$

once you find $u$ from the first equation you can find also $v$ from the second, the third one gives $w$.

Comment: in the Jordan form , why must put before the block with multiplicity 2 ?

Comment: @xmaionx We mustn't, we are free to take $-1$ before. Both are valid Jordan forms.

Comment: @xmaionx Note indeed that if we change J we also find a different order for the basis.